# How to boil sushi rice for yakimeshi?

Tags: rice, boiling, sushi, broth, bouillon

I want to use some chicken bouillon cubes I have to flavor the sushi rice I have, which I'm going to use to make yakimeshi (Japanese fried rice) in accordance with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHoBqDRxaFE).
I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but this is what I've gathered after googling/reading some answers:

- I should keep rinsing the rice until the water is clear
- The ratio for
  short-grain Japanese rice is supposed to be 1 cup of rice:1 cup of
  water (or liquid?)
- I should use 50% broth and 50% water for boiling the rice

The cubes say that 2 cubes make 1 quart (4 cups) of broth, so if I wanted to make 2 cups of broth, I would use 1 cube. Thus, I would use 1 cube to boil 4 cups of rice (in 2 cups water and 2 cups broth).

Am I doing everything right?

Also, do I need to add salt if I'm using broth?

Answer (score 1):

Typically bouillon cubes include a pretty hefty dose of salt, so you're probably fine without adding more. You can always salt the finished fried rice if it needs more seasoning.

All your calculations look fine to me, but one thing you might need to consider is that the salt would raise the boiling point of the broth and potentially affect how the rice cooks.  Probably not a big deal, but if the recipes you've found are particularly insistent that the rice be cooked *only* with water, that might be why.  Just hedge any cooking times a little and check the rice as it cooks, and you'll be fine.

Comment: The amount of salt you would need to make the broth notably affect how the rice cook would also make the rice inedibly salty. It really is a nonissue in most cooking applications(in boiling liquid).